# LSTM X Values are shifted on the prediction?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

## Intro and questions:

I'm somewhat new to Keras and deep learning and I'm trying to predict Tesla stock prices using an LSTM. I’m a definitely a machine learning/deep learning beginner so I was hoping someone with some more knowledge and experience could help guide me in the right direction.

My network is performing well on the y-value predictions. But it seems like the x-values are shifted too far to the left towards the origin. It seems like if I shifted the data over to the right, the predictions would actually be pretty good.
Below is a picture of the prediction plot:

[image: Prediction]

I'm pretty sure the error is coming from when I make the X_test array of values. Below is all the code below organized into sections:

---

### Dataset:

My train data is 4 years of Tesla closing stock prices from 2014-2018. The data I'm going to make the predictions on is the closing stock prices of 2019.

```
# get 2014-2018 data to train our model
start = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018,12,30)
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'yahoo', start, end) 

# get 2019 data to test our model on 
start = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()
test_df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'yahoo', start, end) 

# sort by date
df = df.sort_values('Date')
test_df = test_df.sort_values('Date')

# fix the date 
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
test_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
test_df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

df.tail()
```

```
                  High         Low        Open       Close   Volume  
Date                                                                  
2014-01-02  152.479996  146.550003  149.800003  150.100006  6188400   
2014-01-03  152.190002  148.600006  150.000000  149.559998  4695000   
2014-01-06  150.399994  145.240005  150.000000  147.000000  5361100   
2014-01-07  150.399994  145.250000  147.619995  149.360001  5034100   
2014-01-08  153.699997  148.759995  148.850006  151.279999  6163200   
...                ...         ...         ...         ...      ...   
2018-12-24  314.500000  295.200012  313.500000  295.390015  5559900   
2018-12-26  326.970001  294.089996  300.000000  326.089996  8163100   
2018-12-27  322.170013  301.500000  319.839996  316.130005  8575100   
2018-12-28  336.239990  318.410004  323.100006  333.869995  9939000   
2018-12-31  339.209991  325.260010  337.790009  332.799988  6302300
```

---

### Creating train data:

```
# create train set of adj close prices data:
train_data = df.loc[:,'Adj Close'].as_matrix()
print(train_data.shape) # 1258 


# Apply normalization before feeding to LSTM using sklearn:
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_data = train_data.reshape(-1,1)

scaler.fit(train_data)
train_data = scaler.transform(train_data)


X_train = []
y_train = []
# loop through the data in batches of 36 to create our time steps
print(train_data.shape)
for i in range(36, len(train_data)):
    # append 
    X_train.append(train_data[i-36:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
print(len(X_train))

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
```

The len of train_data before the for loop is 1258 and after the for loop its 1222.

---

### Creating our model:

```
# Build the model 
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units = 100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

---

#### Fitting the model

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size = 10, validation_split=.30)

Train on 855 samples, validate on 367 samples
Epoch 1/20
855/855 [==============================] - 14s 17ms/step - loss: 0.0099 - val_loss: 0.0061
Epoch 2/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0035 - val_loss: 0.0059
Epoch 3/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0036 - val_loss: 0.0057
Epoch 4/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0029 - val_loss: 0.0042
Epoch 5/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - val_loss: 0.0092
Epoch 6/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0025 - val_loss: 0.0039
Epoch 7/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - val_loss: 0.0047
Epoch 8/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0027 - val_loss: 0.0034
Epoch 9/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0023 - val_loss: 0.0035
Epoch 10/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0020 - val_loss: 0.0029
Epoch 11/20
855/855 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0018 - val_loss: 0.0033
Epoch 12/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0021 - val_loss: 0.0027
Epoch 13/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0018 - val_loss: 0.0025
Epoch 14/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0019 - val_loss: 0.0038
Epoch 15/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0019 - val_loss: 0.0037
Epoch 16/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0018 - val_loss: 0.0023
Epoch 17/20
855/855 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0017 - val_loss: 0.0025
Epoch 18/20
855/855 [==============================] - 8s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0015 - val_loss: 0.0021
Epoch 19/20
855/855 [==============================] - 8s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0015 - val_loss: 0.0025
Epoch 20/20
855/855 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0016 - val_loss: 0.0023
```

---

### Model loss plot:

[image: Model loss]

---

### Creating test data (BUG here probably):

```
# Predict with the model and plot predictions  
inputs = test_df['Adj Close'].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = scaler.transform(inputs)

print(len(inputs)) # 159 

X_test = []
y_test = []
for i in range(36, len(inputs)):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-36:i, 0])

X_test = np.array(X_test)
print(len(X_test)) #123
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
#print(predictions)
```

What's interesting is the `len(inputs)` is = 159 before going into the for loop and the coming out of the for loop the `len(X_test)` is = 123. I'm using this for loop to create batches of 36 days of stock prices so our LSTM can take into consideration 36 days of prices before making the prediction. But it seems like it's cutting off the last 36 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

If anyone finds this from google I figured it out. I changed the train and test data creation code to this:

```
'''Function to create a dataset to feed into an LSTM'''
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

# Create the data to train our model on:
time_steps = 36
X_train, y_train = create_dataset(train_data, time_steps)

# reshape it [samples, time steps, features]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 36, 1))

print(X_train.shape) # 1222, 36, 1
```

---

### Test Data:

```
# Get the stock prices for 2019 to have our model make the predictions
test_data = test_df['Adj Close'].values
test_data = test_data.reshape(-1,1)
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)

# Create the data to test our model on:
time_steps = 36
X_test, y_test = create_dataset(test_data, time_steps)

# store the original vals for plotting the predictions 
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1,1)
org_y = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)

# reshape it [samples, time steps, features]
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 36, 1))

# Predict the prices with the model
predicted_y = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_y = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_y)
```

---

### New predictions:

I changed it to plot the original y vals stored in `org_y` and then plot our predicted y vals

```
plt.plot(org_y, color = 'red', label = 'Real Tesla Stock Price')
plt.plot(predicted_y, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted Tesla Stock Price')
plt.title('Tesla Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Tesla Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Predict]